# The CentOS Error use "service td-agent status"

Tags: centos, fluentd

I use td-agent in CentOS.

When I typed "service td-agent start", I saw "Starting td-agent: [ OK ]".
To check it, I typed "service td-agent status", but I saw "td-agent dead but pid file exists".
I don't understand this result.
Please tell me how to solve this.

more
when I typed "service td-agent start", I saw this messages.

```
Starting td-agent: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.39/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:30:in `initialize': Permission denied - /var/log/td-agent/td-agent.log (Errno::EACCES)
from /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.39/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:30:in `open'
from /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.39/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:30:in `init'
from /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.39/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:79:in `start'
from /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.39/lib/fluent/command/fluentd.rb:141:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.39/bin/fluentd:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/bin/fluentd:23:in `load'
from /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/bin/fluentd:23:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/sbin/td-agent:7:in `load'
from /usr/sbin/td-agent:7:in `<main>'
                                                       [FAILED]
```

Comment: I also get "td-agent dead but pid file exists". Start message seems fine, only displays [OK]

Comment: did you look into td-agent.log? mine showed that the S3 credentials supplied were incorrect, and changing them fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the permission issue but you can still check the following link to install and properly configure td-agent on http://docs.treasure-data.com/articles/td-agent

It has also installation notes for redhat/centos/ubuntu.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking permissions as suggested above, delete your pid file before you restart td-agent.  The pid file tracks the process ID for td-agent when you start the service.  If yours isn't located at /var/run/td-agent/ then check /etc/init.d/td-agent and look for something like $PIDFILE